# Reset setinterval on click

Tags: jquery

I've written this simple Carousel. At the moment I'm using setInterval to run my nextSlide function at certain intervals. I want to defer the timer from running when a user clicks on the navigation links for a certain length of time.

Check it out here
http://jsbin.com/uzixi3/3/edit

Any feedback on how the rest is written would be good too.

Comment: One last bit, don't pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`, pass a direct function reference like in my revision, you'll avoid many headaches this way, plus it's more efficient to boot :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do something like this: http://jsbin.com/uzixi3/5/edit

The interval part is here:

```
var int = setInterval($.fn.nextSlide, 3000);
$("#slideNavigation a").click(function() {
  clearInterval(int);
  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval($.fn.nextSlide, 3000);
  }, 10000);
});
```

I made some other tweaks as well though, for example you can use a `switch` statement to make `.nextSlide()` much more readable and cheaper.

Overall though, there's no reason to make these functions as extension methods on jjquery itself since they don't interact with objects, they can just be methods scoped to the closure like this: http://jsbin.com/uzixi3/6/edit

If the methods were actually running on `$('#slideContainer')`, e.g. `$('#slideContainer').nextSlide()` and inside your methods you used `this.animate()` and `this.css()` it might make a bit more sense, just some thoughts that may help you get more flexible as you go.

Comment: Cheers Nick. Thanks for the advice, most helpful

Comment: hihi, had much to fun playing with the sliders to answer in time ;-)

Comment: Example 2 starts acting unexpectedly after you click the next button. The interval length is two different lengths adding up to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

You can save the return value of `setInterval` in a variable to refer to it later - that way you can cancel it if you need to, or restart it.

See [this MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) for more details.

The basics are:

```
intervalID = setInterval(flashText, 1000);

//do something...

clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code really helped.  Thanks Nick.  I made a few minor adjustments so that once you clicked the function: the timer would stop, the function would execute, and then the timer initiates and resumes regular intervals.

make sure you re-assign the `var int` to the new `interval` you create within the `click function`.

```
var int = setInterval(change_slide, 5000);
$("#div").click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
  clearInterval(int);
  setTimeout(function() {
  int = setInterval(change_slide, 5000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
var IntID = setTimer();

function setTimer(){
    i = setInterval(startSlider, 4000);
    return i;
}

function stopSlider() {
    clearInterval(IntID);
}

//Restart Timer

// Option 1 make a restartSlider function and call it
$("#button").click(restartSlider);
function restartSlider(){
    IntID = setTimer();
}

//Option 2 create an anonymous function only for that click event.
$("#button").click(function(){
    IntID = setTimer();
});
```